# realloc не работает, хотя должен

Tags: c, realloc

На строке: "line = (char*)realloc(line, (i+1)*sizeof(char));" вылетает, если ввести больше чем 80 символов.

gdb вытаёт это:
[image: Что выдаёт gdb]
Я ввёл 127 символов и произошла ошибка, причём line выводится корректно.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 80
#define ERRORallocateLine "Failed allocate line successfully...\n"
#define ERRORallocateFlights "Failed allocate flights successfully...\n"

typedef struct Flight
{
    int id; // ID рейса
    int quantityPassengers; // Кол-во пассажиров
    char *from; // Адрес начала строки, содержащую информацию откуда будет выполняться рейс
    char *target; // Адрес начала строки, содержащую информацию куда будет направляться рейс
    char *plane; // Адрес начала строки с названием самолёта
    int relevant; // Флаг, который показывает, актуальный ли рейс: F = 0 or T = !F;
}flight;

/*Формирует рейс*/
flight FormAndInputFlight();
/*Ввод сколь угодно длинной (ага) строки*/
char* Input(FILE*);


int main()
{
    flight one; // Какой-то рейс
    one = FormAndInputFlight();
    printf("|%d|%s|%s|%s|%d|%c|\n", one.id, one.from, one.target, one.plane, one.quantityPassengers, (one.relevant?'Y':'N'));
    return 0;
}



flight FormAndInputFlight()
{
    flight one; // Структура, содержащая 1 рейс
    int buff; // Буффер для ввода чисел
    printf("Input id of flight: ");
    do
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &buff);
        if(buff <= 0)
            printf("Flight number cannot be negative. Input again: ");
    }while(buff <= 0);
    one.id = buff;

    printf("Where does the plane fly from?\n");
    one.from = Input(stdin);

    printf("Where does the plane fly to?\n");
    one.target = Input(stdin);

    printf("What is the name of the plane?\n");
    one.plane = Input(stdin);

    printf("Input number of passengers of flight: ");
    do
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &buff);
        if(buff < 0)
            printf("Number of passengers cannot be negative. Input again: ");
    }while(buff < 0);
    one.quantityPassengers = buff;

    printf("Is the flight up to date? (0 = NO and 1 = YES): ");
    scanf("%d", &(one.relevant));

    if(one.from == NULL || one.target == NULL || one.plane == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed allocate flight successfully...\n");
    }
    return one;
}


/*
df - Указатель на структуру, с помощью которой будет производиться чтение строки
*/
char* Input(FILE *df)
{
    char *line = NULL; // Указатель на начало считываемой строки
    char *buff = NULL; // Указатель на начало строки (нужно для reallock)
    int i, // Счётчик для цикла
        max; // Максимальный размер строки
    int c, // Временный символ
        allOK; // Флаг успешности чтения или выхода
    line = (char*)malloc( (N+1) * sizeof(char));
    max = 1;
    i = 0;
    if(line != NULL)
        do
        {
            max += N;
            while(i < max && (c = fgetc(df)) != '\n')
            {
                line[i] = c;
                i++;
            }
            if(c == '\n')
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    line[i] = '\0';
                    line = (char*)realloc(line, (i+1)*sizeof(char)); // Тут и вылетает. realloc на уменьшение, чтобы line не занимал слишком много места (i на этом шаге = кол-ву символов в line)
                    allOK = 1;
                }
                else
                    allOK = 0;
            else
            {
                allOK = 0;
                buff = line;
                line = (char*)realloc(line, (i+N) * sizeof(char)); //Если есть ещё что считать, то нужно увеличить line, чтобы туда ещё вместилось. Это realloc на увеличение
                if(line == NULL)
                {
                    allOK = 1; //Чтобы выйти
                    printf(ERRORallocateLine);
                    free(buff);
                    buff = NULL;
                }
            }
        }while(!allOK);
    else
        printf(ERRORallocateLine);
    return line;
}
```

Comment: Обычные имплементации realloc в случае если новый размер меньше чем текущий, ничего не делают и просто возвращают указатель. Если Вы реально хотите это сделать - нужно ручками выделить нужное количество памяти и скопировать. Но не факт, что Вы получите какой-то существенный выиграш.

Comment: Учту на будущее. Но почему вылетает то?

Comment: И не стоит делать `foo = realloc(foo, ...);`.

Comment: даже realloc на уменьшение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Везде после чтения чисел `scanf("%d", &buff);` нужно считать из буфера всё до перевода строки.

```
scanf("%d", &buff);
while ( getchar() != '\n') ;
```

При чтении `Input()` первый символ лишний `'\n'` мешает.

Comment: Спасибо. Можно узнать как вы пришли к такому выводу?

Comment: Отладкой посмотрел, что первый символ равен '\n' и сразу увеличился буфер до 161. И тут дошло, что первые символы '\n' бывают после `scanf`. Так оно и оказалось.

Comment: У меня ещё и неправильно работала функция Input()... Спасибо. Кто вы такие, люди со stackoverflow?